# Holo light color code of Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-theme, color-codes

What is the hex color code of the background of the view you draw out in the navigation drawer in the image (the left one) below? I found https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml but cant seem to find the correct color.

[image: I am looking for the Holo Light color (left image)]

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947156/what-are-the-default-color-values-for-the-holo-theme-on-android-4-0/10382463#10382463)

Comment: i've seen that as well but i don't know which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, the background of the Option 1 element is #e7e8e9.